# Task Scheduler Behaviour

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have few questions regarding Task Scheduler behaviors. Suppose we set a task scheduler at a particular date-time, lets say on a schedule of 4/2/20 at 11:00PM:

1. If I shut down or restarted the device multiple times in between set time & scheduled time. but the machine is on at the scheduled time, will it run or fail?
2. If the device is completely off at the scheduled time then what will happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Question 1: The task will run.
- Question 2: This depends on the task settings in the task scheduler. If enabled, the task should run after the scheduler service is started (by the operating system after the boot).

The best advice is just to test it with an easy sample task.

Comment: Q1: It is working
Q2: I checked Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed. The task started after I turn on the device, but took some time.
Is there any delay defined?

Comment: So, is there anything from your original question left?